# How to subtract an array from an array?

Tags: arrays, perl

When I try the following

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @bl = qw(red green blue);
my @a = qw(green yellow purple blue pink);

print Dumper [grep {not @bl} @a];
```

I get an empty array. I would have expected that `@bl` was subtracted from `@a`, so the output was `yellow purple pink`.

What's wrong here?

Comment: “subtract” is not the right word here. When you **do** find the right word, you’ll discover it to be one that triggers a Pavlovian hash attack.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to turn `@bl` into a hash to perform the set difference:

```
my %in_bl = map {$_ => 1} @bl;
my @diff  = grep {not $in_bl{$_}} @a;
```

Comment: This is better than the faq answer for this question -- the faq only shows you how to compute the "symmetric difference" between two arrays

Comment: In Perl 5.10 or newer you could write it `my @diff = grep{ not $_ ~~ @bl } @a;`

Comment: @BradGilbert and 6 years later you get a warning that it's an experimental feature. That comparison may change in the future.

Comment: @BradGilbert The docs state that the smartmatch will match `$_` against each element in `@bl`.  This answer only has to iterate over `@bl` once to make the hash, so there's a significant difference in performance.
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator

Answer (score 4):

See [perlfaq4: How do I compute the difference of two arrays?](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfaq4#How_do_I_compute_the_difference_of_two_arrays?_How_do_I_compute_the_intersection_of_two_arrays?)

In your code, `not` is probably not doing what you think it is doing.

`not @bl` will always be `1` if `@bl` is an empty array, and `undef` if `@bl` is not empty.
It doesn't mean "elements not in `@bl`" in any sense.

Answer (score 4):

`@b1` evaluates to true (it's an array with a non-zero number of elements), so the boolean test in your grep construct (`not @b1`) will always return false. grep filters an array returning only the elements for which the boolean test returns true.

You need to test to see whether `$_` (the array element currently under consideration) is in `@bl` or not. One way to do this is to generate a temporary hash using `@bl` as the keys, then in your grep statement check for the presence of `$_` in the hash keys:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @bl = qw(red green blue);
my @a = qw(green yellow purple blue pink);

# create a hash
my %h;

# nifty trick - use a hash slice to populate the
# hash. The values are irrelevant so we'll use @bl
# for those too
@h{@bl} = @bl;

print Dumper [grep {!exists $h{$_}} @a];
```

Comment: Populating the values of `%h` is overkill. If you use `exists`, populating with `@h{@bl}=()` will be just fine and probably faster.

Answer (score 4):

*Since Perl 5.18.0 the smartmatch operator is considered experimental:
[The smartmatch family of features are now experimental](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod#The-smartmatch-family-of-features-are-now-experimental).
Because of that I wouldn't use this solution below any more.*

Another way with the Smartmatch-operator ( if you have perl-version 5.010 or greater ):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;

my @bl = qw(red green blue);
my @a = qw(green yellow purple blue pink);

my @s = grep{ not $_ ~~ @bl } @a;
say "@s"; # yellow purple pink
```

Comment: Won't this result in `O(n^2)` performance, since the smartmatch operator matches against each element of `@bl` for each element in `@a`?

Comment: @Floegipoky: Your comment sounds reasonable to me. With Perl 5 I stopped using the smartmatch operator. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option using [perl5i](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl5i/):

```
use perl5i::2;

my @bl = qw(red green blue);
my @a = qw(green yellow purple blue pink);
my @diff = @a->diff(\@bl);

say @diff->mo->perl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using the `minus` function from the [Acme::Tools](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Acme%3a%3aTools) CPAN module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Acme::Tools qw(minus);

my @bl = qw(red green blue);
my @a  = qw(green yellow purple blue pink);
my @diff = minus(\@a, \@bl);
print Dumper(\@diff);

__END__

$VAR1 = [
          'yellow',
          'purple',
          'pink'
        ];
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to use:

```
List::Compare CPAN module
use List::Compare ;
...
my $compare_obj 
  = List::Compare->new(\@a , \@b1) ;
@diff = $compare_obj->get_Lonly() ;
...
```