# How to subtract an array from an array / Array minus Array - PERL

Tags: arrays, perl, compare, subtraction

I have arrays like below and I can't find good solutions to make it works:

my @a = qw( A A B C C D D );

my @b = qw( A B C C D );

and as a result I would like to get: @a - @b = (A D)

Thanks for help!

Comment: You're looking for pseudo-code, tips on how to do it, or the code to do it? Because we don't see that you've put any work into getting a solution.

Comment: code or just a proper command.

I tried:

my @new= grep{ not $_ ~~ @B } @A;


and also commands from this:


http://search.cpan.org/~zmij/Array-Utils-0.5/Utils.pm


But it doesn't work as I would like to

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891898/how-to-subtract-an-array-from-an-array)

Comment: I tried this but if I have for example @a=(A A) and @b=(A) and @a-@b gives me nothing. It seems like it checks if element A is present in array, if yes it removes all "A".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my %b;
++$b{$_} for @b;
grep { --$b{$_} < 0 } @a
```

Comment: I tried this one and for now it looks fine!

Thanks a lot for help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find some code an explanation here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=2461

Comment: This won't work if the array contains some elements more than once.